# How to install .car file in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How to install a carbon application in WSO2 API Manger 
I am getting the below error and not able to view the car file after installation.

2020-03-10 14:22:46 INFO  Deploying Carbon Application : ShadowCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car...
2020-03-10 14:22:46 WARN  No artifacts found to be deployed in this server. Ignoring Carbon Application :

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 API Manager does not support deploying .car files at the moment. If you want to use a car file for the integration use case, then you can deploy in ESB/EI and proxy that via API Manager.