# API Manager 4.1.0 import CAR by apictl

Tags: wso2, apim

Is it possible to import CAR archive via apictl into the api manager? Or maybe is there another way to import this archive? I can't use carbon console.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626464/how-to-install-car-file-in-wso2-api-manager

Comment: When I change the server role to capp/APIManager before exporting the CAR archive, then I can upload the archive to apim, but only through the carbon console. My archive only contains files for the gov registry. Is there any other option for this?

Comment: apictl does not support adding car apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CarbonAppUploader admin service to deploy carbon applications in WSO2 products. Refer to the [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/wso2-admin-services/) for more details on how to see the available admin services and use them.